# LibUsb error: device address collision with root hub

Tags: java, usb, usb4java

Im having issues with this line of code. I was able to successfully open the device and send .

Sending:

```
retCode = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(devHandle, endpointSend, buf, iBuf, timeout);
```

Receiving:

```
retCode = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(devHandle, endpointReceive, messageBuf, iBuf, timeout);   
logger.debug("Receiving Message Status: "+retCode);
```

Output:

For Sending, I got a response of 0 but in receiving, I got -7.

```
Receiving Message Status: -7

libusb: error [init_device] program assertion failed: device address collision with root hub
```

Other logs

```
receiveMessage messageBuf: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1000 cap=1000]
receiveMessage iBuf: java.nio.HeapIntBuffer[pos=1 lim=1 cap=1]
```

References searched:

http://usb4java.org/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.usb4java.LibUsb.ERROR_TIMEOUT

```
public static final int ERROR_PIPE  -9
public static final int ERROR_TIMEOUT   -7
```

sometimes it is -9 when I disconnect and connect the device but usually -7. Since I have been playing with the timeout for a while now, I'm beginning to suspect that it is about the pipe. How do I resolve a -9 Error Code?

Comment: Does it work in C? What kind of device is it? Sure that there is no kernel driver attached and that devHandle is valid?

Comment: @Erlkoenig have not tried in C. It is an Android device. How do I check the kernel driver? Im pretty sure that the devHandle is valid as I opened and sent a request to the device successfully

Comment: Highly likely just a wrong error message. This looks like normal TIMEOUT error code, which just means that the device did not send data during `timeout` interval.

Comment: @TurboJ any docs that can help me with this one?

Comment: Try increasing timout to over `9000`? No idea, depends on your hardware.

Comment: I tried increasing to 50000 and still the same issue occurs @TurboJ

Comment: @TurboJ - does this logs help? >                                                                           
         receiveMessage messageBuf: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=1000 cap=1000]
receiveMessage iBuf: java.nio.HeapIntBuffer[pos=1 lim=1 cap=1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sometimes it is -9 when I disconnect

Should always be -9, as a disconnect clears the USB handle inside the kernel.

> For Sending, I got a response of 0 but in receiving, I got -7.

That is the regular `ERROR_TIMEOUT`, which may or may not be an error at all.

The basic meaning is just: The USB device did not send any data on the endpoint during the `timeout` period.

In the (example) case of an USB2UART chip, the `ERROR_TIMEOUT` would just mean that there were no bytes received on the UART RX line.

Fun fact: LibUsb.bulkTransfer() can receive *zero* bytes from a USB device, and would *not* return an error code in this case. USB bulk endpoints actually allow that (and it is different from the "no data at all" case).

Comment: Note: A common case of `ERROR_TIMOUT` would be a protocol error when communicating with a device.

Comment: Actually I just put a timeout between creating the connecting and sending the bulktransfer and receiving got me a responseCode of 0